# In a react project, why can't I see images saved specifically in a directory called public/icons when running npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, image, directory

In my react app, I originally saved my website logo specifically in a directory called `public/icons`. These images showed up for me when I'm developing using `npm start` but when I try to host using `npm run build`, these images are not found.

My solution was to move my logo to a different directory called `public/logos` and this works fine.

The way I get image resources is:

```
const logo = url.resolve(
  process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
  "/logos/logo.png",
);
```

**However, I still don't understand why there was a problem with using `public/icons` in the first place?**

Comment: After `npm run build`, in the "build" directory, there is no directory named "icons"? Did you use CRA to bootstrap your project?

Comment: you may wanna check [using public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Comment: @AjeetShah I did use CRA. Also, in my "build" dir there does exist a dir named "icons" with the logos after running `npm run build`. 

As an aside, the final step that I took after running `npm run build` was to copy all the files into a separate folder for deployment by using `cp -r build/* ../other-dir`(which also contains the "icons" dir + logos)